# R, printing newlines from imported text with escaped characters

Tags: r, string

I am using R with `jsonlite` to read in a JSON file like this:

```
{
    "VEVENT": [
    {
        "DTSTAMP": "20150608T021037Z",
        "DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles": "20150608T173000",
        "DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles": "20150608T183000",
        "STATUS": "CONFIRMED",
        "SUMMARY": "Meeting ABC",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"
    }
    ]
}
```

Say I have access to the description string as the variable `f`, then

`writelines(f)` outputs `Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3`. How can I modify `f` to output

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: What exactly is in `f`? Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, do you mean `writeLines()` rather than `writelines()`? If you don't have a vector, consider using `cat()` instead.

Comment: I was unable to load your JSON string using `fromJSON()` because R complained about the carriage returns (\n).

Answer (score 1):

More info should be added, but here's a start,

```
x <- 'Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3'
cat(x)
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

After dropping that text into `test.json`, I can do this:

```
library(jsonlite)
x <- data.frame(fromJSON("~/Desktop/test.json", flatten = TRUE))
cat(x$VEVENT.DESCRIPTION)
```

to get:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

then write to file with:

```
file.create("description.txt")
fileConn <- file("description.txt")
writeLines(x$VEVENT.DESCRIPTION, fileConn)
```